# Jmockit dependency with jdk17

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jmockit, java-17

Moving from JDK 8 to JDK 17.

jmockit 1.24 is working fine with JDK 8

I tried the newest version jmockit 1.49 with JDK 17
And having error "Jmockit didn't get initialized"

Does jmockit 1.49 support JDK 17?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jmockit 1.49 doesn't support JDK 17.